# how to restrict users to insert only numbers in a TextInput?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I want that the users will be able to insert only numbers in a specific TextInput. Anybody knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextInput.html#restrict

You can use a range like so:

In AS3:

`myTextInput.restrict = '0-9';`

In Flex:

`<mx:TextInput id="myTextInput" restrict="0-9" />`

I haven't tested this, but it should work just fine, according to the docs.